# Geopraphic Charting controls for Websites

Tags: web, charts, geospatial, dashboard

I need to create dash boards showing geographic regions and show sales, hot spots etc on a map.

What have you tried and what do you recommend?

I like the look of both [Fusion Charts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/maps/Default.asp) and [Dundas](http://www.dundas.com/Components/Products/Map/NET/index.aspx)

I will be using asp.net for the site but any control's or library's including flash or javascript are good options.

Most important is the look and feel followed by functionality in South Africa.

After my last post looking for commercial mapping solutions, it looks like they are very expensive and now I am investigating alternatives to full mapping solutions.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.geoext.org/examples.html#examples a JavaScript library based opn top of OpenLayers and ExtJS.

You can limit the bounds of your map to different regions, have several pop-up maps etc. 
Have a look at the OpenLayers API on what datasources you can use. GeoJSON or KML are probably easiest if you want to avoid server-side map serving software.